# executing "initialize_qserve_db" leads to an error

Tags: python, initialization, sqlalchemy, pyramid

when I execute

```
../bin/initialize_qserve_db  production.ini
```

I get this error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) column name is not unique u'INSERT INTO models (name, value) VALUES (?, ?)' ('one', 1)
```

I am pretty new to Pyramid. Can anyone tell where should I look for mistakes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have *already* run that command; the row with values `'one', 1` already exists.

Comment: Nope, the database has been set up and data has been inserted already.